# how to get recent_token inside MyFirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` method to get token inside my `FcmInstanceIdService` but as these are deprecated, I trying to rewrite this code -

```
public class FcmInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    public void onTokenRefresh()
    {
        String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN), recent_token);
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

to -

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
           String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
           Log.e("newToken",newToken);

         }
      });
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
       editor.putString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN), recent_token);
       editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
}
```

I am unable to get which Activity should I pass as `MyActivity` in `addOnSuccessListener` while getting `recent_token`.

Old code reference - https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/sending-push-notification-to-android-application-from-your-own-django-app-server
but this is not properly working because FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated, now trying to make it work.

I found the solution form - https://medium.com/android-school/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated-50651f17a148

If you any other solution regarding my old code reference please share.

Comment: Check my answer @pankaj-sharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to call `getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener` inside `onNewToken` as you have already got the newToken with argument `s`. So try like below:

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN), s);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: I want to ask, when this method is triggered, can we store to Firebase by get the value `s` ?

Comment: @Md. Asaduzzaman thank you, its compiling without any errors but I am it is not sending the token along with url, I am getting this - `/insert/?fcm_token=` at my server, please help me

Comment: Check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.html#onNewToken(java.lang.String)

Comment: Quoted from there: `This is invoked after app install when a token is first generated, and again if the token changes`. So you can create a service to sync this token with server

Comment: @PankajSharma, I didn't see anything in your implementation about server sync. I see you store the token in `SharedPreference`

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code from - https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/sending-push-notification-to-android-application-from-your-own-django-app-server

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I am unable to understand why token is empty on sending GET request to url, server is getting - `/insert/?fcm_token=`

Comment: If you follow the tutorial correctly then inside `onClick` didn't you get token using `final String token = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN), "");
`

Comment: If you get `token` then you have to add it like `app_server_url+token` which is done in the tutorial.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman `onNewToken` is not triggering automatically but I use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInst...` previous code in `MainActivity` and it worked.